# How to disable real time compilation in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to disable the real time compilation in Visual Studio 2015?

It's grinding to a halt whenever I make changes that have a ripple effect throughout my dependent code. The error list updates even before saving the C# file I'm working on, filling it with CS**** compiler errors as I'm typing.

Comment: Not an answer to this question but it was the first one that came out when I was trying to stop VS from underlining errors for the sake of taking screenshots, so if you only want to hide the error lines, not disable the compilation, you can change the color for "syntax error" to the background color as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40651072/175157

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In visual Studio 2015 go to `tools`, `options`, `text editor`, `C#`, `Advanced` and uncheck **Enable full solution analysis**. This should stop your problem as the solution won't be checked every time unless you build it.

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Downvoted because doesn't work. VS will still underline my function and complain that it lack a `return` statement until I get to the end type it. Obviously, the original poster (and I) need the behavior of good old VS2008, which did not check your code until you told it to compile it.

Comment: And you downvoted because your current version doesn't do whatever you would like it to have done back 10 years ago. And how is that my fault? Don't forget the author marked this as resolved, so surely this will have worked for them.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but I want to post a screenshot of what my Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced section looks like.

I am using VS2015 Community Update 1 and I do not have the "Enable full solution analysis" option, or some of the other ones in the screenshot above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options -> Text Editor\C# -> Advanced:
Uncheck "Underline errors" and "Show live semantic errors".
Its also called compile on save.
Worked on MS Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, haven't installed the 2015 yet.

Comment: You're right, those options exist in 2013, they're nowhere to be found in 2015.

Comment: Well, I just installed VS 15, and the settings are gone, maybe they get patched in. But until then, there is no option to enable compile on save, maybe you have to rollback. Sorry that I can't help you.

Comment: Very frustrating! I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507844/vs-2015-high-cpu-usage-on-file-save

Comment: The question is clearly about VS 2015, probably most of us land here because we are aware the option existed

Answer (score 1):

I just disable this in the Error List window. There is a drop down with these options:

- Build + IntelliSense
- Build Only
- IntelliSense Only

If I select **Build Only**, it does not try to find compilation errors in real time.

Comment: Downvoted, because the *Error list* window is only part of the issue. *VS* still underlines things it doesn't like as you type them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options -> TextEditor -> C# -> Advanced. Under Editor Help, disable "show diagnostics" for closed files. This option disables the analyzers from running on all closed files in the solution and the analysis is performed only on the Open/Active files in VS.

Comment: I don't have that option. See the screenshot posted by Marcos Placona above

Comment: How to disable analysis on *all* files?

Answer (score -1):

I found one setting in Resharper. Sheck it and you dont see the squiggles.
Resharper Options/Code Inspection/Settings/Visual Studio integratinon/Suppress Visual Studio squiggles.

Comment: I always assumed that this was just a visual change - do you find that suppressing the squiggles prevents real time compilation from being performed?