# Disabling red squiggly lines in visual studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using visual studio 2015 as my script editor for unity and I'd like to get rid of the syntax error underlining because they irritate me a lot, but I can't find the option to do that in visual studio. Can the syntax underlining be disabled for C#?

I've searched for answers but I couldn't find an answer that worked for me, 
The solution should apparently be to go to Options>Text Editor>C#>Advanced and change some settings there, but none of the options I have seem to remove the squiggly lines.

Here's my option menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckRtE.png

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=Disabling+red+squiggly+lines+in+visual+studio+2015+C%23

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was gonna vote down for using bing but I just realized you work for Microsoft.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov do you think I can't use search engines? none of those have helped me. That is why I came here.

Comment: Sorry for offtop but I agree - bing and yahoo search engines maybe are not that bad, but the problem is, all the time one installs malware, his browser has default search engine switched to bing or yahoo. Great marketing MS and Yahoo. Just great - I promise I will never use your search engines even if it was last on planet.

Comment: @Xcorpius I believe you are not interested *to show* that you can use search engines. Couple lines like "I tried ... settings " would show what you tried and improve post a lot. I have no idea what your overall search skills are - but it has no impact on quality of the post (which unfortunately suffered as you did not provide results of your search in the post).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I see, you're right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might try changing the *color* of the squiggly lines by going to tools -> options -> environment -> fonts and colors -> syntax error and setting the color to one that doesn't irritate you. Like white.

Comment: This was useful for taking screenshots of code snippets for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question for Visual studio 2019 (and maybe other versions), as I also needed this for talking screenshots with non-compiling code, so here is the settings (took me a while to find!), for what it's worth:

[image]